# Trying to add different cooldowns for the same command (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Missao', 'missão', 'missao', 'm'])
async def mission(ctx, rank = None):
    if f'{ctx.channel.id}' == '745647726804336702':
        if rank == None:
            await ctx.send('Voce nao especificou o rank da missao!')
        elif rank == 'E' or rank == 'e':
            responses = ['Salve o gato na arvore!', 
            'Limpe a rua, esta cheia de lixo.', 
            'Um bando de delinquentes pixou o muro da praca, por favor limpe-os.', 
            'Outono chegou, as folhas estao caindo, poderia recolher algumas por favor.']
            missionEmbed = discord.Embed(
                title = "Missao Rank E",
                description = f'{random.choice(responses)}',
                colour = discord.Colour.green()
            )
            missionEmbed.add_field(name = 'Recompensa', value = '1.000 - 5.000 :moneybag:\n 1 - 10 **SP**', inline = True)
            missionEmbed.add_field(name = 'Linhas', value = '30', inline = True)
            missionEmbed.set_author(name = f'Missao de {ctx.message.author.nick}', icon_url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed = missionEmbed)
        elif rank == 'D' or rank == 'd':
            responses = ['Um bandido esta assaltando o restaurante!', 
            '2 garotos estao brigando do lado da escola, pare-os.']
            missionEmbed = discord.Embed(
                title = "Missao Rank D",
                description = f'{random.choice(responses)}',
                colour = discord.Colour.blue()
            )
            missionEmbed.add_field(name = 'Recompensa', value = '6.000 - 10.000 :moneybag:\n 11 - 25 **SP**', inline = True)
            missionEmbed.add_field(name = 'Linhas', value = '60', inline = True)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed = missionEmbed)
        else:
            await ctx.send('Os ranks sao E/D!')
```

So if you use the command '>mission' you can choose a rank for the mission (e or d), and i'd like for each of them to have their own cooldown, and not a cooldown for the actual mission command

Comment: Cooldown based on a condition say Role would come under Global Checks as far I know. Consider looking into those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way you can do that is by separating the mission command into multiple different commands and using an `@command.cooldown` .

However, if you really don't want to do that, you can create a function that checks the cooldown for you and you can call it to the mission command. Just a suggestion. Try out modules that have to do with time.

Comment: yep, i couldn't find a way to do it so i just created diff commands for each mission, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad I helped :)